# Control 12v relay in series with 3.3v

Tags: mosfet, relay, esp32

I would need to control 4 relays (300 mA each) with an esp32.

Relay will open and close at the same time so i not need a dedicated control.

As I'm not expert I would like to ask you if you can propose a solution (I'm thinking of a MOSFET) to drive the 4 relays.

Many thanks

Comment: You can purchase relay boards with a suitable driver cheaply. There must be a zillion blogs that show how to do this. Let Google guide you.

Comment: The Common quad  relay boards use Rs + 1.2V IR optocouplers that work off low voltage then 12V for an isolated switch to coil. But you can ignore the isolated Vdd and 12V if you start with shared grounds. These will also include coil flyback diodes and LEDs and terminal blocks yet are very inexpensive. Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score -1):

Use the industry standard ULN2003 relay driver.

It can drive up to 7 relays with a current of 500 mA per channel.

The maximum total collector input current is 2.5 A

It can handle voltage outputs up to 50 V.

It also has 7 free wheeling diodes and 7 reverse protection diodes.

It contains 7 bipolar transistor BJT's instead of 7 MOSFETs.

BJTs are more robust than MOSFETs.

[image]

---

I'm using Texas Instruments ULN2003 since 2003 and never had a problem.

ULN2003 is an industry standard integrated circuit and is manufactured by:

```
ON Semiconductor
Texas Instruments
ST Micrcoelectronics
Diodes incorporated
Toshiba
```

Here's a selection:

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/transistors-bipolar-bjt-arrays/277?s=N4IgjCBcpgnAHLKoDGUBmBDANgZwKYA0IA9lANogAMIAusQA4AuUIAykwE4CWAdgOYgAvkOIAmCiACu2XmKpUAzHSFA

Comment: Bjts vs mosfets - how did you come to such a conclusion? Just because you haven't had a problem, doesn’t mean that the solution would work in all instances.